# Symfony2 Ajax call to display a message on a specific condition

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, symfony

I am beginner in javascript and ajax and I just cant figure out how to display a message on some condition.

Lets say a user can increase or decrease the quantity of the product he wants to buy. I have made that (not saying it was easy). But if the product is out of stock he cant increase the quantity anymore. How can I show that in the message. For example if a user tries to increase the quantity, but the product is out of stock I want to display the message below **on the same ajax call**.

This is the controller:

```
public function addQuantityAction( Request $request ) {
    $response = new JsonResponse();
    $requestData = $request->request->all();
    $productid     = $requestData['product'];
    $quantity = $requestData['quantity'];
    /** logic*/
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $product = $em->getRepository('MpShopBundle:Product')->find($productid);
    $qtyAvailable = $product->getStockAvailable();
    $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
    $cart = $session->get('cart', array());
    if ( $qtyAvailable > $cart[ $productid ] ) {
        $cart[ $productid ] = $cart[ $productid ] + 1;
        $qtyAvailable = $qtyAvailable - 1;
        $response->setData(array('success'=>true,'message'=>'Qunatity increased','amount'  => $cart[ $productid ]));
         $session->set('cart', $cart);
    } else {
        $response->setData(array('success'=>false,'message'=>'Out of stock'));
    }
    return $response;
}
```

The Ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.add', function (e) {
    $this = $(this);   
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'add',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: {product: $this.parent('.input-append').find('input').data('id'),quantity: $this.parent('.input-append').find('input').val()},
        success: function (data) {      
          if(data.success == false){
           alert('error')
          }else{
            $('.test').load(" .test");
            $('.sidebar').load(" .sidebar");
            $('.top').load(" .top");
           }
        }
    });
```

And the twig:

```
<div class="input-append">

   <input class="span1" style="max-width:34px" placeholder="{{ key }}" value="{{ item }}" id="appendedInputButtons" size="16" type="text" data-id="{{ key }}"/>
   <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="remove btn"><i class="icon-minus"></i></a>
   <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="add btn"><i class="icon-plus"></i></a>                   
   <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button"><a href="{{ path('cart_remove', {'id': key}) }}"><i class="icon-remove icon-white" style="color:white"></i></a></button>

    <p> display message here </p>

                        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also add class depands on success or error status of operation.

Ajax

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.add', function (e) {
    $this = $(this);   
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'add',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: {product: $this.parent('.input-append').find('input').data('id'),quantity: $this.parent('.input-append').find('input').val()},
        success: function (data) {      
          if(data.success == false){
           alert('error')
          }else{
            if(data.message != 'undefined') {
                $('#ajax_response--message').html(data.message)
            }
            $('.test').load(" .test");
            $('.sidebar').load(" .sidebar");
            $('.top').load(" .top");
           }
        }
    });

<div class="input-append">
```

Twig

```
    <p id="ajax_response--message"> display message here </p>

                        </div>
```